# How fill with month year in array when not exists?

Tags: php, arrays

From the database I am bringing some data from a range of dates, the problem is that there are years and months that are not generated.
How can I fill the array with the months and years that do not exist in the array?

Get data from database from 2018-10-01 00:00:00 to 2019-06-10 23:59:59

This is the result

```
array:9 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2018
    "month" => 10
    "total" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2019
    "month" => 2
    "total" => 2
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2019
    "month" => 3
    "total" => 4
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2019
    "month" => 5
    "total" => 3
  ]
]
```

---

But how fill the empty months?

```
array:9 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2018
    "month" => 10
    "total" => 3
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2018
    "month" => 11
    "total" => 0
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2018
    "month" => 12
    "total" => 0
  ],
  3 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2019
    "month" => 1
    "total" => 0
  ]
  4 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2019
    "month" => 2
    "total" => 2
  ]
  5 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2019
    "month" => 3
    "total" => 4
  ]
  6 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2019
    "month" => 4
    "total" => 0
  ]
  7 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2019
    "month" => 5
    "total" => 3
  ]
  8 => array:3 [
    "year" => 2019
    "month" => 6
    "total" => 0
  ]
]
```

I try many method but I do not have good results.

Comment: give us more details, show your code, anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the min and max values for year, then iterate over those values and build the array manually, filling in the total column if present:

```php
<?php
$array = [
    ["year" => 2018, "month" => 10, "total" => 3],
    ["year" => 2019, "month" =>  2, "total" => 2],
    ["year" => 2019, "month" =>  3, "total" => 4],
    ["year" => 2019, "month" =>  5, "total" => 3]
];
$minyear = min(array_column($array, "year")); // 2018
$maxyear = max(array_column($array, "year")); // 2019
$fullarray = [];
foreach (range($minyear, $maxyear) as $year) {
    $yeardata = array_filter($array, function($item) use ($year) {
        return $item["year"] === $year;
    });
    $minmonth = $year === $minyear ? min(array_column($yeardata, "month")) : 1;  // for first year find the min month
    $maxmonth = $year === $maxyear ? max(array_column($yeardata, "month")) : 12; // for last year find max month
    foreach (range($minmonth, $maxmonth) as $month) {
        $monthdata = array_filter($yeardata, function($item) use ($month) {
            return $item["month"] === $month;
        });
        $value = count($monthdata) ? array_values($monthdata)[0]["total"] : 0;
        $fullarray[] = array(
            "year" => $year,
            "month" => $month,
            "total" => $value
        );
    }
}
var_dump($fullarray);
```

Comment: First month return value correct but the other months return ever total = 0

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the resulting array and check for the presence of a month&year with `in_array()`.

Try this example code:

```
<?php

$arrayTot = array
(
    0 => array
    (
        "year" => 2018,
        "month" => 10,
        "total" => 3
    ),
    1 => array
    (
        "year" => 2019,
        "month" => 2,
        "total" => 2
    ),
    2 => array
    (
        "year" => 2019,
        "month" => 3,
        "total" => 4
    ),
    3 => array
    (
        "year" => 2019,
        "month" => 5,
        "total" => 3
    )
);

$startDate = '2018-10-01';
$startYm = date('Ym', strtotime($startDate));
$endDate = '2019-06-10';
$endYm = date('Ym', strtotime($endDate));

$actualYm = $startYm;
while($actualYm <= $endYm)
{
    $year  = substr($actualYm, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($actualYm, 4);

    $inArray = false;
    foreach($arrayTot as $k => $v)
    {
        if(in_array($year, $v) && in_array($month, $v))
        {
            $inArray = true;
        }
    }

    if(!$inArray)
    {
        //echo "missed $year-$month\n";
        $arrayTot[] = array
        (
            "year" => "$year",
            "month" => "$month",
            "total" => 0
        );
    }

    $actualYm = date('Ym', strtotime("{$actualYm}01 +1 month"));
}
print_r($arrayTot);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2018
            [month] => 10
            [total] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2019
            [month] => 2
            [total] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2019
            [month] => 3
            [total] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2019
            [month] => 5
            [total] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2018
            [month] => 11
            [total] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2018
            [month] => 12
            [total] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2019
            [month] => 01
            [total] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2019
            [month] => 06
            [total] => 0
        )
)
```

Comment: This looks more like suggestions than an answer(so more a comment)

Comment: I try you suggestions

Comment: @NigelRen I was writing the code, now it's complete.

Comment: @user2342558 not return the array correctly, see the exapmle, I need return all month when not exists return the value total to 0.

Comment: @Alexd2 give me one example please, it seems to be correct inserting `totale = 0` when the month is missed

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another approach to this:

```
$arr = [
  0 => [
    "year" => 2018,
    "month" => 10,
    "total" => 3,
  ],
  1 => [
    "year" => 2019,
    "month" => 2,
    "total" => 2,
  ],
  2 => [
    "year" => 2019,
    "month" => 3,
    "total" => 4,
  ],
  3 => [
    "year" => 2019,
    "month" => 5,
    "total" => 3,
  ],
];

$start_year = 2018;
$start_month = 1;
$end_year = 2019;
$end_month = 12;
$size = count($arr);
$end = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    if ($arr[$i]["year"] != $start_year || $arr[$i]["month"] != $start_month) {
        array_splice($arr, $i, 0, [['year' => $start_year, 'month' => $start_month, 'total' => 0]]);
        if (!$end) {
            $size++;
        }
    }
    $start_month++;
    if ($start_month == 13) {
        $start_month = 1;
        $start_year++;
    }
    if ($i == ($size - 1) && ($arr[$i]['month'] != $end_month || $arr[$i]['year'] != $end_year)) {
        var_dump($arr[$i]['month']);
        var_dump($end_month);
        var_dump($arr[$i]['year']);
        var_dump($end_year);
        echo "\n\n";
        $arr[$i + 1] = ["year" => 0, 'month' => 0];
        $size++;
        $end = true;
    }
}
array_pop($arr);
```

Comment: @Alexd2 It was returning a notice, but I have removed that. Look at the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding try removing and set your array pre-filled with your desired entries. Total you can fill 0 by default and change when entry matches.